# Assign second story board controller to first story board tab bar item.

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have two story board in my project. First storyboard has tab bar controller with 5 item. I want to assign second story board controller to one tab bar item.So how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a storyboard reference of that. There you will option to assign Storyboard name and its Reference ID.

[image: Storyboard reference]

Comment: how can do it through tab bar item .

Comment: Just drag and make a segue from _tab bar controller_ to the _storyboard reference_. This will create a new Tab Bar child view controller for the tab bar.